# Get versions from npm registry api

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-registry

I'm looking for a way to query npm package versions from the npm registry api.
All I found until now is that I need to query the whole package metadata and filter the versions from there, Example: https://registry.npmjs.org/react-chuck/

It's ok for package with small amount of versions but for large amount of versions it's just too much time to query.

I thought that maybe there is something like the dist-tags api that query only the dist-tags, Example: https://registry.npmjs.org/-/package/react-chuck/dist-tags , the dist-tags are in the same scope as versions...
[image]

I don't mind to do it cli also `npm view react-chuck versions` but this returns array as a string and array of strings.

I looked at those two links:

- https://github.com/npm/npm-registry-client
- https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/REGISTRY-API.md

Anyone has a tip of champs maybe?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
npm show react-chunk time --json
```

Comment: Any way I can do this using HTTP API ?

Comment: sure, but like the `npm show` command the HTTP API will return all the metadata for the package so you'd need to filter out the data you want.    
For example:
`curl https://registry.npmjs.org/react-chunk | jq .time`

Comment: `graph-ql` was an ingenious invention, do they know it ?

Comment: @jbachman what you suggest return `Your credentials could not be authenticated: "Credentials are missing.". You will not be permitted access until your credentials can be verified.`

Answer (score 3):

Check https://github.com/npm/registry/blob/master/docs/responses/package-metadata.md

You need to vary the `Accept` header to return abbreviated package metadata. Request the NPM registry directly, not with the npm CLI.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know there's no command that will fetch only part of the data.

The `npm view react-chunk versions` command still fetches from https://registry.npmjs.org/react-chuck and then parses it on the client side. It's indeed not very efficient for packages with a lot of versions, but that's the api.

Comment: The timestamps are of course inside the full json fetched from https://registry.npmjs.org/react-chuck/

Comment: Any way I can do this using HTTP API ?